# How to fix android resource linking failed error in Android

Tags: android

I trying to open an Android project in Android Studio but I am getting the following error

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2331: error: resource anim/abc_popup_enter (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:anim/abc_popup_enter) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2332: error: resource anim/abc_popup_exit (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:anim/abc_popup_exit) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2335: error: resource anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2336: error: resource anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2339: error: resource anim/abc_tooltip_enter (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:anim/abc_tooltip_enter) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2340: error: resource anim/abc_tooltip_exit (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:anim/abc_tooltip_exit) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2503: error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2506: error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_text_material (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_btn_colored_text_material) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2560: error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2612: error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2644: error: resource color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2647: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_primary_text_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2648: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_light (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_primary_text_material_light) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2649: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2650: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2651: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2652: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2653: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2654: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2655: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light (aka com.example.kontrol.mydictation:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light) not found.

>Command: C:\Users\kontrol\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\f2b7042c25ae8ac78b6339cc492412a8\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\kontrol\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.kontrol.mydictation\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\kontrol\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictation\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

I am using Android Studio 3.4.1. I don't understand what is causing this problem?

Comment: have you recently upgraded or reinstalled android studio?